# Spring Integration: inbound-gateway management is slower by 20 seconds instead of @Controller management

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-integration

I have two Spring MVC applications; I'm using Spring Integration HTTP to integrate them.

**The process**

The process is very simple: an HTTP GET request directed to the *"application1"* is managed by a `@Controller` and then "transfered" to the *"application2"* with an `<int-http:outbound-gateway>` through an HTTP POST.

Once there, this POST (intermediate) request is managed and transfered to another URI of the *"application2"* (with another `<int-http:outbound-gateway>`), **that provides the real response**.

**The issue**

I have noticed a different behaviour in the request management on the *"application2"* side (which is invoked by the `<int-http:outbound-gateway>` of the *"application1"*).

If I use a `@Controller` to manage the "intermediate" URI, the process execution needs some milliseconds to be accomplished.

But if I use an `<int-http:inbound-gateway>` to replicate the same process, **it needs 20 seconds to complete the process**: why this difference?

This is the implementation with the `@Controller`:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/service")
public class ServiceController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/{resource}", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public void resource(@PathVariable(value="resource") String resource, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse res){
        handleRequest(resource,request, res);
    }

    private void handleRequest(String resource, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse res) throws Exception {
        // READING THE REQUEST PAYLOAD
        RequestHandler requestHandler = RequestHandler.getHandler(request);         
        RequestPayload payload = requestHandler.getPayload();

        // PREPARING THE MESSAGE TO THE CHANNEL
        MessagingChannel messagingChannel = (MessagingChannel)ApplicationContextResolver.getApplicationContext().getBean("requestChannelBean");
        MessageChannel requestChannel = messagingChannel.getRequestChannel();
        MessagingTemplate messagingTemplate = new MessagingTemplate();
        String url = request.getScheme()+"://"+request.getServerName()+":"+request.getServerPort()+request.getServletContext().getContextPath()+request.getServletPath()+"/"+resource;
        Message<?> requestMessage = MessageBuilder.withPayload(url).build();

        // SEND THE MESSAGE AND RECEIVE THE RESPONSE
        Message<?> response = messagingTemplate.sendAndReceive(requestChannel, requestMessage);

        // PRINT THE RESPONSE
        res.getWriter().write((String)response.getPayload());

    }
}
```

This solution works perfectly and it needs a few milliseconds to return the response.

The following is the implementation with the `<int-http:inbound-gateway>` and the `<int:service-activator>` that I'm trying to use to **replicate** the `@Controller` solution:

```
<int:service-activator id="channelServiceActivator"
    ref="channelService"
    input-channel="requestChannel"      
    method="manage"/>

<int-http:inbound-gateway id="gateway" request-channel="requestChannel"
              path="/service/**" 
              supported-methods="POST"
              header-mapper="headerMapper">
    <int-http:header name="requestAttributes" expression="#requestAttributes"/>
</int-http:inbound-gateway>
```

With this service activator:

```
public class ChannelService {

    public String manage(Message<?> message) throws Throwable{

        // RECOVERING THE HttpServletRequest
        ServletRequestAttributes sra = (ServletRequestAttributes) message.getHeaders().get("requestAttributes");
        HttpServletRequest request = sra.getRequest();

        // RETRIEVING THE PAYLOAD
        Object payload = message.getPayload();

        // PREPARING THE MESSAGE TO THE CHANNEL
        MessagingChannel messagingChannel = (MessagingChannel)ApplicationContextResolver.getApplicationContext().getBean("requestChannelBean");
        MessageChannel requestChannel = messagingChannel.getRequestChannel();
        MessagingTemplate messagingTemplate = new MessagingTemplate();
        String url = request.getScheme()+"://"+request.getServerName()+":"+request.getServerPort()+request.getServletContext().getContextPath()+request.getServletPath()+"/"+resource;
        Message<?> requestMessage = MessageBuilder.withPayload(url).build();

        // SEND THE MESSAGE AND RECEIVE THE RESPONSE
        Message<?> response = messagingTemplate.sendAndReceive(requestChannel, requestMessage);

        // RETURN THE RESPONSE
        return (String) response.getPayload(); // <- since here, the behaviour is normal. 
                                               // The framework needs 20 seconds after this instruction

    }
}
```

**This implementation needs 20 seconds to be completed for every request**, I don't understand the reason for that.
I don't see any error in the Spring logs, I only see that the system seems to "freeze": it not logs anything anymore for 20 seconds.

Any explanation would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**

Here the logs.
After the "HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData:101", it needs 20 seconds before seing the others "org.springframework.integration.http" logs (2016-07-29 15:06:18 -> 2016-07-29 15:06:38).

```
2016-07-29 15:06:18 TRACE [] org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.close:217 (http-nio-8080-exec-4) - Logical connection closed
GenericMessage [payload={
  "_embedded" : {
    "persons" : [ ]
  },
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/application2/api/persons"
    },
    "profile" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/application2/api/profile/persons"
    },
    "search" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/application2/api/persons/search"
    }
  }
}, headers={Transfer-Encoding=chunked, Server=Apache-Coyote/1.1, Accept=application/json, X-Content-Type-Options=nosniff, Pragma=no-cache, http_statusCode=200, Date=1469797578000, X-Frame-Options=DENY, Cache-Control=no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate, id=2b6b0b80-82bc-2ce7-c364-1e84c389bc71, X-XSS-Protection=1; mode=block, contentType=application/json, timestamp=1469797578411}]
2016-07-29 15:06:18 DEBUG [] org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse:658 (executor-1) - POST request for "http://localhost:8080/application2/api/service/persons" resulted in 200 (OK)
2016-07-29 15:06:18 DEBUG [] org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData:101 (executor-1) - Reading [java.lang.String] as "application/octet-stream" using [org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter@5397e277]
2016-07-29 15:06:38 DEBUG [] org.springframework.integration.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper.toHeaders:436 (executor-1) - inboundHeaderNames=[*]
2016-07-29 15:06:38 DEBUG [] org.springframework.integration.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper.shouldMapHeader:537 (executor-1) - headerName=[server] WILL be mapped, matched pattern=*
2016-07-29 15:06:38 DEBUG [] org.springframework.integration.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper.toHeaders:463 (executor-1) - setting headerName=[Server], value=[Apache-Coyote/1.1]
2016-07-29 15:06:38 DEBUG [] org.springframework.integration.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper.shouldMapHeader:537 (executor-1) - headerName=[pragma] WILL be mapped, matched pattern=*
2016-07-29 15:06:38 DEBUG [] org.springframework.integration.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper.toHeaders:463 (executor-1) - setting headerName=[Pragma], value=no-cache
2016-07-29 15:06:38 DEBUG [] org.springframework.integration.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper.shouldMapHeader:537 (executor-1) - headerName=[accept] WILL be mapped, matched pattern=*
2016-07-29 15:06:38 DEBUG [] org.springframework.integration.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper.toHeaders:463 (executor-1) - setting headerName=[Accept], value=[application/json]
2016-07-29 15:06:38 DEBUG [] org.springframework.integration.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper.shouldMapHeader:537 (executor-1) - headerName=[host] WILL be mapped, matched pattern=*
2016-07-29 15:06:38 DEBUG [] org.springframework.integration.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper.toHeaders:463 (executor-1) - setting headerName=[host], value=[localhost:8080]
2016-07-29 15:06:38 DEBUG [] org.springframework.integration.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper.shouldMapHeader:537 (executor-1) - headerName=[connection] WILL be mapped, matched pattern=*
2016-07-29 15:06:38 DEBUG [] org.springframework.integration.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper.toHeaders:463 (executor-1) - setting headerName=[connection], value=[keep-alive]
2016-07-29 15:06:38 DEBUG [] org.springframework.integration.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper.shouldMapHeader:537 (executor-1) - headerName=[cache-control] WILL be mapped, matched pattern=*
2016-07-29 15:06:38 DEBUG [] org.springframework.integration.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper.toHeaders:463 (executor-1) - setting headerName=[Cache-Control], value=no-cache
2016-07-29 15:06:38 DEBUG [] org.springframework.integration.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper.shouldMapHeader:537 (executor-1) - headerName=[user-agent] WILL be mapped, matched pattern=*
2016-07-29 15:06:38 DEBUG [] org.springframework.integration.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper.toHeaders:463 (executor-1) - setting headerName=[user-agent], value=[Java/1.8.0_65]
2016-07-29 15:06:38 DEBUG [] org.springframework.integration.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper.shouldMapHeader:537 (executor-1) - headerName=[x-xss-protection] WILL be mapped, matched pattern=*
2016-07-29 15:06:38 DEBUG [] org.springframework.integration.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper.toHeaders:454 (executor-1) - setting headerName=[X-XSS-Protection], value=[1; mode=block]
2016-07-29 15:06:38 DEBUG [] org.springframework.integration.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper.shouldMapHeader:537 (executor-1) - headerName=[x-frame-options] WILL be mapped, matched pattern=*
2016-07-29 15:06:38 DEBUG [] org.springframework.integration.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper.toHeaders:454 (executor-1) - setting headerName=[X-Frame-Options], value=[DENY]
2016-07-29 15:06:38 DEBUG [] org.springframework.integration.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper.shouldMapHeader:537 (executor-1) - headerName=[x-content-type-options] WILL be mapped, matched pattern=*
2016-07-29 15:06:38 DEBUG [] org.springframework.integration.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper.toHeaders:454 (executor-1) - setting headerName=[X-Content-Type-Options], value=[nosniff]
2016-07-29 15:06:38 DEBUG [] org.springframework.integration.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper.shouldMapHeader:537 (executor-1) - headerName=[content-type] WILL be mapped, matched pattern=*
2016-07-29 15:06:38 DEBUG [] org.springframework.integration.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper.toHeaders:463 (executor-1) - setting headerName=[Content-Type], value=application/octet-stream
2016-07-29 15:06:38 DEBUG [] org.springframework.integration.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper.shouldMapHeader:537 (executor-1) - headerName=[content-length] WILL be mapped, matched pattern=*
2016-07-29 15:06:38 DEBUG [] org.springframework.integration.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper.toHeaders:463 (executor-1) - setting headerName=[Content-Length], value=968
2016-07-29 15:06:38 DEBUG [] org.springframework.integration.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper.shouldMapHeader:537 (executor-1) - headerName=[date] WILL be mapped, matched pattern=*
2016-07-29 15:06:38 DEBUG [] org.springframework.integration.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper.toHeaders:463 (executor-1) - setting headerName=[Date], value=1.469.797.578.000
answer: {
  "_embedded" : {
    "persons" : [ ]
  },
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/application2/api/persons"
    },
    "profile" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/application2/api/profile/persons"
    },
    "search" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/application2/api/persons/search"
    }
  }
}
2016-07-29 15:06:38 TRACE [] org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest:138 (http-nio-8080-exec-2) - Method [sendMessageToChannel] returned [null]
2016-07-29 15:06:38 DEBUG [] org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult:1044 (http-nio-8080-exec-2) - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
2016-07-29 15:06:38 TRACE [] org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.resetContextHolders:1062 (http-nio-8080-exec-2) - Cleared thread-bound request context: SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository$Servlet3SaveToSessionRequestWrapper@9bacc4f]
2016-07-29 15:06:38 DEBUG [] org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest:1000 (http-nio-8080-exec-2) - Successfully completed request
2016-07-29 15:06:38 TRACE [] org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent:362 (http-nio-8080-exec-2) - Publishing event in WebApplicationContext for namespace 'dispatcher-servlet': ServletRequestHandledEvent: url=[/application1/api/persons/]; client=[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]; method=[GET]; servlet=[dispatcher]; session=[null]; user=[null]; time=[21426ms]; status=[OK]
2016-07-29 15:06:38 TRACE [] org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent:362 (http-nio-8080-exec-2) - Publishing event in Root WebApplicationContext: ServletRequestHandledEvent: url=[/application1/api/persons/]; client=[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]; method=[GET]; servlet=[dispatcher]; session=[null]; user=[null]; time=[21426ms]; status=[OK]
2016-07-29 15:06:38 DEBUG [] org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter:117 (http-nio-8080-exec-2) - Chain processed normally
2016-07-29 15:06:38 DEBUG [] org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter.writeHeaders:130 (http-nio-8080-exec-2) - Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@7ffcc692
2016-07-29 15:06:38 DEBUG [] org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper.saveContext:352 (http-nio-8080-exec-2) - SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
2016-07-29 15:06:38 DEBUG [] org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter:119 (http-nio-8080-exec-2) - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

**UPDATE 2**

I have investigated more the process:

- The `outbound-gateway` (application1) sends a message to a remote endpoint (application2) with the "`sendAndReceive()`"; the message contains the header "`application/octet-stream`", because I pass a Byte Array as payload.
- The remote endpoint (application2) has an `inbound-gateway` with a service activator
- The `service activator` (application2) processes the request and returns a String.
- The `HttpMessageConverterExtractor` (application1) try to read the response with the *contentType* of the message that has been sent to the "application2" (`application/octet-stream`).

I think that the problem is right here: I have sent a message with the `outbound-gateway` with the header `application/octet-stream`, **but in response I have to receive a String** (with `application/json`), **not an application/octet-stream**.

These are the informations of the `inputMessage` variable used by the `readInternal` method of the class `org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter`:

```
inputMessage    MessageBodyClientHttpResponseWrapper  (id=111)  
    pushbackInputStream PushbackInputStream  (id=146)   
    response    SimpleClientHttpResponse  (id=121)  
        connection  HttpURLConnection  (id=125) 
        headers HttpHeaders  (id=182)   {Server=[Apache-Coyote/1.1], Pragma=[no-cache], Accept=[application/json], host=[localhost:8080], connection=[keep-alive], Cache-Control=[no-cache], user-agent=[Java/1.8.0_65], X-XSS-Protection=[1; mode=block], X-Frame-Options=[DENY], X-Content-Type-Options=[nosniff], Content-Type=[application/octet-stream], Content-Length=[968], Date=[Mon, 01 Aug 2016 12:52:47 GMT]}
        responseStream  HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream  (id=180)
```

The *Content-Type* is `application/octet-stream`, but **this must to be refered only to the message in outbound**, not for the inbound message obtained in answer!

There is any way to configure the content type of the response that can receive an outbound-gateway?

My Service activator of application2 process the answer in this way:

```
public class ChannelService {

    public String manage(Message<?> message) throws Throwable{          
        ServletRequestAttributes sra = (ServletRequestAttributes) message.getHeaders().get("requestAttributes");
        HttpServletRequest request = sra.getRequest();
        System.out.println(request.getRequestURL());

        Object payload = message.getPayload();

        return "{ \"test\" : \"test\"}";
    }

}
```

**UPDATE 3**

The problem is the `InputStream` obtained by the `HttpInputMessage` with `inputMessage.getBody()`.

While this InputStream is processed with the "`read()`" method, the result of the "`read()`" is never -1 for 20 seconds.
I have implemented a custom `StringHttpMessageConverter`:

```
@Override
protected String readInternal(Class<? extends String> clazz, HttpInputMessage inputMessage)
        throws IOException, HttpMessageNotReadableException {
    System.out.println("ResponseStringHttpMessageConverter.readInternal()");

    int content;
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    while ( ( content = inputMessage.getBody().read()) != -1){
        System.out.println(content);
        baos.write(content);
    }   
    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("TIME READING: "+(end-start));
    String response = baos.toString();
    System.out.println(response);
    return response;
}
```

The custom `readInternal` method prints every single character ASCII code, after the last character it stops printing and when it restarts it prints:

```
TIME READING: 20164
```

So I suppose that there is something wrong in the InputStream of the message, because the read() method doesn't return "-1" before 20 seconds.

**UPDATE 4**

I solved the problem in the Converter side, but there is the same problem in the closing of the response in the `doExecute()` method of the `org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate` class.

The method try to close the response (an instance of `org.springframework.http.client.SimpleClientHttpResponse`):

```
@Override
public void close() {
    if (this.responseStream != null) {
        try {
            StreamUtils.drain(this.responseStream); // <- again the same problem
            this.responseStream.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) { }
    }
}
```

This is the `"drain"` implementation of `org.springframework.util.StreamUtils` class:

```
public static int drain(InputStream in) throws IOException {
    Assert.notNull(in, "No InputStream specified");
    byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
    int bytesRead = -1;
    int byteCount = 0;
    while ((bytesRead = in.read(buffer)) != -1) { // it blocks here !!!
        byteCount += bytesRead;
    }
    return byteCount;
}
```

In my converter I solved the problem using a buffer with the expected available buffer size:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[in.available()];
in.read(buffer);
baos.write(buffer); // (a simple ByteArrayOutputStream)
```

I definitely convinced that there is something wrong in my configuration of the outbound-gateway / inbound-gateway / service activator, because the response cause a block just before reading the -1 byte of EOS.
Otherwise there would be a bug, and I don't believe in this option.

Comment: Please, share debug logs for `org.springframework.integration` to see the real journey of your "slow" message.

Comment: I have updated the question with the logs of org.springframework.integration

Answer (score 1):

According to you logs:

```
2016-07-29 15:06:18 DEBUG [] org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData:101 (executor-1) - Reading [java.lang.String] as "application/octet-stream" using [org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter@5397e277]
2016-07-29 15:06:38 DEBUG [] org.springframework.integration.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper.toHeaders:436 (executor-1) - inboundHeaderNames=[*]
```

It looks like you have very big response which takes that time for converting to `String`.

See `HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(ClientHttpResponse response)`.

There is nothing what Spring Integration does for.

Would be better if you'd debug that `StringHttpMessageConverter.readInternal(Class<? extends String> clazz, HttpInputMessage inputMessage)` and have a look what is your real response.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll try to investigate this issue.

Comment: For your information, the application freezes in the `java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.class`, in the `while` cycle of the `runWorker` method. I have tried to increase the value of the `pool-size` attribute of the `<task:executor>` tags, but it didn't solve the problem. It's exaclty in that point that the application waits for 20 seconds.

Comment: It's correct that your thread executor is blocked and nothing else can use it, but that isn't a cause . You exactly have a problem with the response.

Comment: I have added some informations about the content-type that I receive in the answer for the outbound.gateway; it's an `application/octet-stream`, but it must be different and it's probably the cause of the long-time conversion.

Comment: Now I have found the reason of the issue: the inputStream doesn't return -1 before 20 seconds. Now I have to understand why!

Comment: same problem in the closing of the response in RestTemplate.class (StreamUtils.drain method)

Comment: Thanks Artem for your help. I have found a solution, check it if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem, but in order to solve it, I had to create a **custom** `RestTemplate`.

In my custom RestTemplate I have *overrided* the method "`doExecute()`".

The implementation is the same of the original RestTemplate.doExecute, except the finally block.

In this block, I don't call "`response.close()`" but I have created a custom method that provides to close the response Client.

This is the custom RestTemplate implementation:

```
public class AppRestTemplate extends RestTemplate {

    @Override
    protected <T> T doExecute(URI url, HttpMethod method, RequestCallback requestCallback,
            ResponseExtractor<T> responseExtractor) throws RestClientException {

        Assert.notNull(url, "'url' must not be null");
        Assert.notNull(method, "'method' must not be null");
        ClientHttpResponse response = null;
        try {
            ClientHttpRequest request = createRequest(url, method);
            if (requestCallback != null) {
                requestCallback.doWithRequest(request);
            }
            response = request.execute();
            handleResponse(url, method, response);
            if (responseExtractor != null) {
                return responseExtractor.extractData(response);
            }
            else {
                return null;
            }
        }
        catch (IOException ex) {
            String resource = url.toString();
            String query = url.getRawQuery();
            resource = (query != null ? resource.substring(0, resource.indexOf(query) - 1) : resource);
            throw new ResourceAccessException("I/O error on " + method.name() +
                    " request for \"" + resource + "\": " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }
        finally {
            if (response != null) {
                 // response.close(); // <- commented; this is the cause of the slow process
                close(response);
            }
        }
    }

    /** This method only provides to close the stream, without draining it */
    private void close(ClientHttpResponse response) {
        try {
            if (response.getBody()!=null){
                response.getBody().close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Obviously I had to register the new RestTemplate in the Application Context configuration:

```
<bean id="restTemplate" name="restTemplate" class="mypackage.integration.AppRestTemplate" autowire-candidate="true">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <bean class="mypackage.integration.ResponseStringHttpMessageConverter" />
            <!-- ... other converters -->
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

**Last but not least**, I also had to implement a **custom converter** that **replace** the original `StringHtppMessageConverter` (in my case, `ResponseStringHttpMessageConverter`):

```
public class ResponseStringHttpMessageConverter extends AbstractHttpMessageConverter<String> {

    private Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ResponseStringHttpMessageConverter.class);

    public ResponseStringHttpMessageConverter() {
        super(new MediaType("application","json"));
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        if (clazz == String.class)
            return true;
        else return false;
    }

    @Override
    protected String readInternal(Class<? extends String> clazz, HttpInputMessage inputMessage)
            throws IOException, HttpMessageNotReadableException {       
        int content;
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] buffer = new byte [inputMessage.getBody().available()];
        inputMessage.getBody().read(buffer);
        baos.write(buffer);
        String response = baos.toString();
        baos.close();
        return response;
    }

    @Override
    protected void writeInternal(String content, HttpOutputMessage outputMessage)
            throws IOException, HttpMessageNotWritableException {

    }

}
```

With this implementation, the requests don't suffer anymore of the slow problem.

P.S. I'm using Spring 4.3.1.RELEASE and Spring Integration 4.3.0.RELEASE.

I think that this is not to be considered a definitely solution, because I had to customize two framework components.

Comment: This solutions is not working properly, because `inputMessage.getBody().available()` never returns the correct amount of bytes contained in the InputStream. However, it's absolutely a problem of the InputStream.